# SBS 2003 only seeing 2 of my 4 CPU cores

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have inherited a network with several SBS 2003 servers in it.

I must say up front that my Windows server knowledege is limited (I'm a linux guy by nature) but I can only see 2 of the 4 cores that are installed (2 dual core processors).

All the digging I've done so far say that I should be able to see all 4 (especially for R2, which I don't think I'm running yet) but I can't.

I'm going to try and rebuild one of the systems (the current backup box) to see if something has not gone correctly with the initial install (using R2 this time) but really don't want to if I'm wasting my time.

Can anyone tell me if I absolutely should be able to see all 4 processor cores in SBS 2003 before I start?  Anything I should watch out for with the install?

Thanks.
Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there options in the BIOS that affect the cores?

Does process explorer and/or coreinfo from Sysinternals (google sysinternals for the download) show anything unusual about the CPU usage?

Is there something with the install or licensing that is limiting the number of cores or CPUs? If it supports X processors and you have x+2 processors, it may have the wrong HAL installed (and as I recall would need to be reinstalled to work properly). If the wrong version is licensed you'd need to get an upgraded edition of Windows.

If you boot the system from a Linux liveboot disc, how many cores does that see? That'll tell you if it's hardware or software that is the root of the issue.

Comment: +1 for potential licensing problems.

Comment: Good suggestion about the Linux boot.. don't know why I didn't think about that myself given my linux bent.. lol.  I'll try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2007/08/17/multi-processor-support-in-microsoft-windows-small-business-server-2003.aspx) is a good article on multi-core processors running SBS 2003. It looks like it should definately show each core as a logical processor. Have you confirmed that the system actually has 2 dual core processors and is not just a dual processor (single core) system? BIOS should show you that.

Comment: Thanks for this Dave, I found this article in my digging, hence my question here as I can't see them. I believe the cores are enabled, but will check on the backup box before I try the re-build.

Answer (score 1):

Some BIOS will let you enable only 1 Dual core at a time. In this settings, you can enable the second dual core. This might be in your CPU Configuration in your BIOS.

Even if you have a x86 or x64 architechture, you're OS should/will see the 2x Dual processors.

Hope that helped!

Regards,

David.